# oauth2 redirect uri. Passing data back to the client

Tags: redirect, oauth, oauth-2.0

I understand that the reason for the redirect uri is to pass the credentials back to the client, which is fine.

I want to allow programmers to use my client_id to write their own implementation, the problem is that my client_id has associated to it a set amount of redirect_uris, thus if the programmer is making their own implementation they cannot redirect to their own page.

I should thus have a single redirect uri which passes the token back to the client, but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing `client_id`s between different apps is not security best practice. You should be looking in to something like Dynamic Client Registration where each client dynamically registers itself together with its redirect URI to the Authorization Server: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7592